# Python and library (wxPython)

Tags: python, wxpython, libs

I'm complety new to Python (coming from Java) and trying to use wxPython library (GUI). I'm using PyCharm as IDE. 
Does anyone know how to use library with Python ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: All you need to do is install wxPython for the Python version you need. Then import it like any other module. There are numerous tutorials and even a couple of books

Answer (score 0):

There are semi-official installation instructions on the [wxPython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython).

If you are installing wxPython Phoenix, you can actually use pip:

```
python -m pip install --no-index --find-links=http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ --trusted-host wxpython.org wxPython_Phoenix
```

If you are on Linux, check your package manager. wxPython is usually included, although it may be an older version. The latest version of Classic is 3.0.2.0. Phoenix is where the project is going and will likely have all or most of the new updates applied to it. If you go with Phoenix, then use the method above as it won't be in the package manager.

If you want to use Classic and it's not in the package manager, then you will have to build wxPython yourself. There are instructions [here](https://wxpython.org/builddoc.php)

Windows and Mac have installers that you can use that can be found here:

- https://wxpython.org/download.php

This is also the location for the wxPython tarball.

wxPython is also supported by Anaconda to some degree. See the following:

- https://anaconda.org/anaconda/wxpython